# Get the minimum of 3 columns in Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

In Vertica, how can I get a column that is the min of 3 existing columns? In the case of a all nulls it should return zero.

I've tried min() function, but realized that it's only returning min of a column.

I thought about a case statement but realized it would be super long to capture every combination of results and would be very resource intensive.

I appreciate any suggestions. Thank you!

[image: my sample data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`LEAST`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/String/LEAST.htm) to get the minimum value of multiple columns per row.

```
select least(coalesce(open_hrs_diff,0),coalesce(click_hrs_diff,0),coalesce(login_hrs_diff,0))
from tablename
```

Comment: LEAST() !!! amazing. I had no idea this existed. Thank you so much! I couldn't figure this out by googling. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: sure..the question title should say "minimum of 3 columns". i edited it accordingly.